# How to install swoole in mac-os

Tags: macos, php-7, swoole

Am trying to install swoole using PHP 7.0.2 in MAMP

```
$ pecl install swoole
Could not open input file:/app/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.2/lib/php/peclcmd.php
```

Is there any alternate way to install it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no luck installing Swoole via home brew or pecl. So I installed it manually and works. So here my step:

Make sure you php installed on your osx

```
php -v

phpize -v
```

Go to temporary folder

```
cd /tmp/
```

Download the source code

```
wget "https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src/archive/v4.0.3.tar.gz" -O swoole.tar.gz
```

Extract the file

```
tar xvzf swoole.tar.gz
```

Go to source folder

```
cd swoole-src-4.0.3/
```

Prepare the build environment for a PHP extension

```
phpize
```

Add configuration paramaters as needed

```
./configure
```

Run make. This will take some time
a successful result of make is module/swoole.so

```
make
```

create Swoole extension directory

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/php71-swoole/
```

install the swoole into the PHP extensions directory

```
cp modules/swoole.so /usr/local/opt/php71-swoole/
```

Create config file for Swoole

```
touch /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-swoole.ini
echo "extension=/usr/local/opt/php71-swoole/swoole.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-swoole.ini
```

check if the swoole extension has been enabled
php -m | grep swoole

If succeed, it will send you output something like "swoole"

PS: I run PHP 7.1 and Swoole 4.0.3. Adjust it with your own version.

Comment: Not at the time when I wrote this answer. But never try it again as for now.

Comment: Thanks worked for me but using "4.8.11" version